# Using C# Task hang nunit and keep running in background with Testflight. How unit test it?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, task-parallel-library, testdriven.net

I'm building a task-based server. My problem is how prove with unit test is working right:

The method below is the core of the app, and need to be solid. I need it to execute the chain of task, sleep if the date to start it is in the future and so on. However when I run it with the nuni gui it hang-up forever, and with http://www.testdriven.net/ add-on it run, and get it running in the background, so I can't stop it from the VS IDE (ie, run, then finish according to the IDE, but keep running in the background and need to kill testdriven to stop it)

```
public Task RunPlan(plan thePlan)
{
    List<BackupTask> tasks = this.nextTasks(thePlan);
    List<Task> backupTasks = new List<Task>();

    TimeSpan wait;
    int i = 1;
    Task run = new Task(() =>
    {
        Logging.Debug("Starting {0}", thePlan);
    });
    //  Create a new token source
    var primaryTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    //  Create the cancellation token to pass into the Task
    CancellationToken token = primaryTokenSource.Token;

    workerTokens.GetOrAdd(run, primaryTokenSource);

    backupTasks.Add(run);

    foreach (var t in tasks)
    {
        BackupTask job = t;

        Task next = backupTasks.Last().ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            //  Check to see if we've been cancelled
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Logging.Debug("Cancelled");
                return;
            }
            //Si es en el futuro, esperar
            wait = job.SuggestedDate - DateTime.Now;

            if (wait.TotalSeconds > 0)
            {
                Logging.Debug("Sleeping {0} secs..", wait.TotalSeconds);
                //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141617/thread-interrupt-to-stop-long-sleep-at-app-shutdown-is-there-a-better-approach
                //Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(wait.TotalSeconds));
                while (!stopping)
                {
                    lock (padlock)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(padlock, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(wait.TotalSeconds));
                    }
                }
            }

            //  Check to see if we've been cancelled
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Logging.Debug("Cancelado");
                return;
            }

            job.doWork();
        },TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning);
        backupTasks.Add(next);
    }

    backupTasks.First().Start();

    return backupTasks.Last();
}
```

And the test:

```
[Test]
public void testFullBackup()
{
    taskMgr.RunPlan(plans.First()).Wait();
    Assert.AreEqual(0, taskMgr.workerTokens.Count());
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your test too?

Comment: I just call the method directly from a Test method, with not assert at all.

Comment: So you don't `Wait()` on it or anything like that? In that case, that could be the problem.